# $.ajax POST call issue in IE for cross domain

Tags: jquery, cross-domain

All,
This could be oft-repeated question..but i have been at this for over a day..and so far its disappointing and frustrating.. :(

```
function (url, requestData) {
var jqryXHR = $.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: anotherDomainurl,
    //contentType: 'application/json; charset=UTF-8',
    data: {
        requestParams: requestData
    }
});
```

}

This works fine in FF and Chrome but not on IE.In IE the call itself is not getting triggered .What should i do to make it work...And requirement is to make call with POST.

My server side code is java and am setting

header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*.anotherDomain.com');

Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Was able to solve the problem finally...

For IE, we would have to use the

Cross-domain Request (XDR) for Cross Domain call..instead of  XMLHttpRequest

Refer :  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd573303%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

There are some restrictions when using XDR which can be viewed @

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ieinternals/archive/2010/05/13/xdomainrequest-restrictions-limitations-and-workarounds.aspx

```
if (window.XDomainRequest) {    
            var xdr = new XDomainRequest();
            xdr.open("POST", url);
            xdr.onload = function () {};
            xdr.onerror = function() {};
            xdr.onprogress = function() {};
            xdr.send("requestData="+jsonData);
    } else{
         jQuery.support.cors = true;
            var jqXHR = $.ajax({
                type : 'POST',
                url : url,
                crossDomain: true,
                data : {
                    requestData : jsonData
                }
        });         
    }
```

Also at server end, the response should have headers added

Access-Control-Allow-Origin,
Access-Control-Allow-Methods,
Access-Control-Allow-Headers

Answer (score 0):

Use jsonp. It provides a method to request data from a server in a different domain.

http://remysharp.com/2007/10/08/what-is-jsonp/

Comment: Thanks I tried with jsonp..but jsonp again triggers a GET call..And am looking for a POST - JSON call                                                   Moreover what is wrong over here in the code that the call itself is not getting triggerd.